# The type 'Context' does not inherit from 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'. with EF migration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have two context and one databases.

I am getting this error when I try to add a database migration (add-migrations).

I have update EF to 6.2.

I checked and the configuration.cs file is using

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MSiH.CigaretteContext>
```

PM> add-migration -configuration MSiH.DataAccess.CigaretteContext -Verbose
cmdlet Add-Migration at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name: Initals
Using StartUp project 'GridAndMap'.
Using NuGet project 'GridAndMap'.

```
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigrationsException: The type
 'MSiH.CigaretteContext' does not inherit from 
'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'. 
Migrations configuration types must extend from
'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'.
at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TypeExtensions.CreateInstance[T]
(Type type, Func`3 typeMessageFactory, Func`2 exceptionFactory)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.MigrationsConfigurationFinder.FindMigrationsConfiguration
(Type contextType, String configurationTypeName, 
Func`2 noType, Func`3 multipleTypes, Func`3 noTypeWithName, Func`3 multipleTypesWithName)
 at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.FindConfiguration()
 at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
 at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
 at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
 at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
 at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Scaffold(String migrationName,    String language, String rootNamespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
 at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.Execute(String name, Boolean force, Boolean ignoreChanges)
 at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
 at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
 The type 'MSiH.EyePaid.CigaretteWebApp.DataAccess.CigaretteContext' does not inherit  
 from 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'. Migrations 
 configuration types must extend from
'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'.
```

**Update**

I was following an [example](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/entityframework/2VOa140214-Entity-Framework-6-Code-First-Migrations-with-Multiple-Data-Contexts.html) about how to use EF Migration with multiple contexts.

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName Foo.CigaretteContext
```

This command was giving the error:

```
Add-Migration -configuration Foo.CigaretteContext Initial
```

This command works:

```
Add-Migration Initial
```

Comment: You have to show your `CigaretteContext' class or we cannot help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Configuration` or `ConfigurationTypeName` parameter refers to a class that is derived from [DbMigrationsConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrationsconfiguration%28v=vs.113%29.aspx).

What you did was referring to a class that is derived from `DbContext`.

You should do this instead.

```
Add-Migration -Configuration MSiH.MigrationDatabaseIfAny.Configuration Initial
```

PS: `MigrationDatabaseIfAny` is a directory name If your `Configuration` class is located under a directory, if not just remove it.